# Why can I not comment, on either my questions or answers or anyone elses?

Tags: support, comments

Why can I not comment, on either my questions or answers or anyone elses ?

- I have much more than 50 reputation
- And a large label placed on my profile says "You've earned a new privilege! You can now Comment everywhere
- My last comment was on 5-June-2020
- I can only think, that maybe it is a browser or other software problem, something that has changed recently on this site, but everything else functions ok.

Comment: have you tried from your phone, for instance?

Answer (score 4):

A few possibilities:

- Sounds like you've got multiple accounts. You can request to have them merged using the contact form at the bottom of the page.
- It could well be a software issue. Comments use some fancy AJAX-based system that doesn't work on some of my devices; make sure your browser [supports HTML5](https://html5test.com/) and ES6.
- Your account has no restrictions that might prevent you from commenting, so that's not a possibility.